# append a span at caret in contenteditable div when I click on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert travelAllowance in between "+" and "basic" as shown in below Image, without deleting the present ones.

[image]

The complete code has given below. I have searched the whole internet but unable to find the answer.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 debugger;
 $("#display").html("");
 var formula = "";
 var data = [
     "BasicPay ",
      "OverTime ",
      "TravelAllowance ",
      "DearnessAllowance ",
      "FoodAllowance ",
      "providentFund "
     ];
    $( "#autofill" ).autocomplete({
      source:data,
      autoFocus: true ,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
       debugger;
   $("#display").append("<span class='block' contentEditable='false'>" + ui.item.value + "</span>");
  $( "input[name='autofill']").val("");
       return false;    
           }
 });  
   $("#showPayTypes").html("Allowed Pay Types are : " + data.toString());  
 $(".operators").click(function(){ 
  debugger;
  var selectedOperator = $(this).html();
  $("#display").append("<span contentEditable='false' class='block'>"  + selectedOperator  + " " + "</span>");
 });
 $("#delete").click(function(){
  debugger;
  if ($("#display span").first().attr('class') == "noClass") {
  var yourString = $.trim($("#display").text());
  var result = yourString.substring(1, yourString.length-1);
  var formulaArray = result.split(" ");
  formulaArray.forEach(main);
  function main(arrayItem, index, array) {
   debugger;
   var regExForOnlyNum = RegExp(/^\d+$/).test(arrayItem);
   if (regExForOnlyNum == true) {
    var bracesSpanObj = "<span contentEditable='false' class='numbers'>" + arrayItem+ " " + "</span>";
    formulaArray[index] = bracesSpanObj;
   }else
   if (arrayItem == '(' || arrayItem == ')') {
    var bracesSpanObj = "<span contentEditable='false'>" + arrayItem+ " " + "</span>";
    formulaArray[index] = bracesSpanObj;
   }
   else 
   if (arrayItem != "") {
      var spanObj = "<span contentEditable='false' class='block'>" + arrayItem+ " " + "</span>";
      formulaArray[index] = spanObj;
   }else{
    $(this).remove();
   };
  }
  $("#display").html(formulaArray);


  /*$("#display").html(result);*/
  /*var result = yourString.slice(1, -1);*/
  /*$("#display span").first().remove();*/
  }else{
    $("#display span").last().remove();
   }
 });
 $("#enterNum").keypress(function(e){
  if (e.which == 13) {
   debugger;
   var text = $("#enterNum").val();
   if (text != "") {
   $("#display").append("<span contentEditable='false' class='numbers'>"+ text + " " + "</span>");
   /*onclick = 'makeItEdit()'*/
   $("#enterNum").val("");
    }else{
     alert("please enter some value....")
     return false;
    };
     }
 });
 $(".numbers").bind
 $(".braces").click(function(){
  debugger;
  var value= $(this).html();
  $("#display").append("<span contentEditable='false'>" + value + " " + "</span>");
 });
 $(".wrapIn").click(function(){
  debugger;
  $("#display").html("<span contentEditable='false' class='noClass'>( " + $("#display").html() + ") "+ "</span>");
 });
 $("#saveFormula").click(function(){
  debugger;
  var formulaForValidation = $.trim($("#display").text());
  alert("the formula created by u is ==" + formulaForValidation);
  var operatorsAtTheEnd = RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9(]+(.*[a-zA-Z0-9%)])*$/).test(formulaForValidation);
  if (operatorsAtTheEnd == true) {
  formula = $("#display").text();
  console.log(formula);
  $("#display").html("");
  }else{
   alert("unfortunately the format you entered is incorrect");
   return false;
  }; 
 });
    
    $("#getFormula").click(function(){
  debugger;
  alert("formula received from server=="+"'"+formula+"'");
  var formulaArray = formula.split(" ");
  formulaArray.forEach(main);
  function main(arrayItem, index, array) {
   debugger;
   if (arrayItem == '(' || arrayItem == ')') {
    var bracesSpanObj = "<span contentEditable='false'>" + arrayItem+ " " + "</span>";
    formulaArray[index] = bracesSpanObj;
   }
   else 
   if (arrayItem != "") {
      var spanObj = "<span contentEditable='false' class='block'>" + arrayItem+ " " + "</span>";
      formulaArray[index] = spanObj;
   }else{
    $(this).remove();
   };
  }
  debugger;
  console.log("formulaArray ===== " +formulaArray);
  $("#display").html(formulaArray);
 });
 /*function makeItEdit(){
  debugger;
 $(".numbers").attr('contentEditable', true);
 }
    */

    $("#display").click(function(e) {
 debugger;
    var target = $(e.target), article;
 if(target.is('.numbers')) {
 $(".numbers").attr('contentEditable', true);
    return false;
    } else {
    $(".numbers").attr('contentEditable', false);
    return false;
    }
 })
});
```

```css
#display{
 padding: 5px;
 border:5px double #c38600;
 width: 682px;
 min-height: 110px;
 margin: 10px auto;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 50px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 color: #abcdef;
 outline: none;
}
#input{
 border: 1 px solid white;
 width: 701px;
 min-height: 50px;
 margin: 5px auto;
}
#autofill{
 width: 500px;
 margin-left: 10PX;
 padding: 2px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid green;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #864566;
}
#autofill:focus{
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid green;
 outline: none;
}
label{
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #864566;
}

#operatorsBlock{
 width: 701px;
 height: 50px;
 border:5px double #c38600;
 margin: 5px auto;
 border-radius: 8px;

/* padding: 10px;*/
}
#showPayTypes{
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 700px;
 height: 50px;
 border:5px double #c38600;
 margin: 10px auto;
 border-radius: 8px;

}
.operators, .braces, .wrapIn{
 border:1px solid rgba(70, 5, 26, 0.18);
 width: 9%;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 6px;
 padding: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-align: center;
}
.block, .numbers{
 border:1px solid blue;
/* width: 40px;
*/ font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}
#functions{
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 150px;
    width: 704px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
button {
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 51px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 27px;
}
#enterNum {
    width: 150px;
    height: 43px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #610854;
}
#inputText{
 margin-top: 35px;
}
#getFormula{
 margin-top: 5px;
}
#wrapInBraces{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Functions.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="display" contentEditable="true"></div>
<div id="input">
  <form>
   
  </form>
   <label for="autofill">Pay Type:<input type="text" name="autofill" id="autofill" /></label>
</div>
<div id="showPayTypes"></div>
<div id="operatorsBlock">
 <span style="margin-left: 10px">
  <span class="operators" id="add">+</span>
  <span class="operators" id="substract">-</span>
  <span class="operators" id="divide">/</span>
  <span class="operators" id="multiply">*</span>
  <span class="operators" id="percentage">%</span>
  <span class="braces">(</span>
  <span class="braces">)</span>
  <span class="wrapIn" title="Insert formula in Braces">("")</span>
 </span>
</div>

<div id="functions">
 <div id="buttons">
  <input type="number" id="enterNum" placeholder="numbers here">
  <button id="saveFormula">Save Formula</button>
  <button id="getFormula">Get Formula</button>
  <button id="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- <span id="wrapInBraces"></span>
 --></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you're trying to do or what's not working.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/5837056/robert-m:: i want to append travel allowance at the cursor position in contenteditable div

Answer (score 1):

You can not give the same click and expect two different behaviors.

One path you can achieve this function is to make elements inside the big box movable. Another path is when you click inside the big box, the coordinate will be remembered, the target you typed below the big box will be inserted to the point remembered.